# Java BMP Header files

Tags: java, image, header, bitmap, bmp

I try to make a BMP file from BufferedImage. Here is function with that I try to write the header and pixels in bmp file.

I have a mistake but I can't find that. I need your help.

```
static void writeToBMP(BufferedImage img, String name)
{
    //File header
    int bfType = 0x424d;
    int bfSize = (img.getHeight()*img.getWidth()*3)+54; // File size
    short bfReserved1 = 0; // Reserved
    short bfReserved2 = 0;
    int bfOfBytes = 54; // Header size

    //Header info
    int biSize = 40; // Header 2 size
    int biWidth = img.getWidth(); // Width in pixels
    int biHeight = img.getHeight(); // Height in pixels
    short biPlanes = 1; // Nr of planes
    short biBitCount = 24; // Nr bites per pixel
    int biCompression = 0;
    int biSizeImage = (img.getHeight()*img.getWidth()*3); // Image size
    int biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    int biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    int biClrUsed = 0;
    int biClrImportant = 0;

    File file = new File(name);

    try {
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fOut = new DataOutputStream(stream);
        fOut.writeShort(bfType);
        fOut.writeInt(bfSize);
        fOut.writeShort(bfReserved1);
        fOut.writeShort(bfReserved2);
        fOut.writeInt(bfOfBytes);

        //Write Header Info
        fOut.writeInt(biSize);
        fOut.writeInt(biWidth);
        fOut.writeInt(biHeight);
        fOut.writeShort(biPlanes);
        fOut.writeShort(biBitCount);
        fOut.writeInt(biCompression);
        fOut.writeInt(biSizeImage);
        fOut.writeInt(biXPelsPerMeter);
        fOut.writeInt(biYPelsPerMeter);
        fOut.writeInt(biClrUsed);
        fOut.writeInt(biClrImportant);
        for(int x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(x,y));
                fOut.writeByte(c.getRed());
                fOut.writeByte(c.getBlue());
                fOut.writeByte(c.getGreen());
            }
        }
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried to write only header, and header size = 54 bytes.

I don't know if I calculate correct the bfSize and biSizeImage.

Comment: Do you have to do this manually or can you use [ImageIO.write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve my problem I need to use LITTLE_ENDIAN byte order. For this I use:

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(54);
    buffer.putInt(bfSize);
    buffer.putShort(bfReserved1);
    buffer.putShort(bfReserved2);
    buffer.putInt(bfOfBytes);
    buffer.putInt(biSize);
    buffer.putInt(biWidth);
    buffer.putInt(biHeight);
    buffer.putShort(biPlanes);
    buffer.putShort(biBitCount);
    buffer.putInt(biSizeImage);
    buffer.putInt(biXPelsPerMeter);
    buffer.putInt(biYPelsPerMeter);

    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buffer.flip();
```

Comment: Padding also has to be taken care of!

Answer (score 2):

Try using ImageIO

```
File outImage = new File(name);
ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", outImage);
```

Comment: With Image.IO I can export but I need to write myself headers and image.

Comment: @unNene What's the difference?

Comment: I have at university this problem, I need to create by myself the bitmap image.

Comment: I see, nothing really stands out as wrong with your code.  I would just research the BMP file format and use a good HEX viewer to double check the output file.

Comment: I founded the problem, I need to use LITTLE_ENDIAN byte format, in other case byte's are in inverse order.